# Javascript drag-and-drop plugins meeting this requirements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I'm using [jquery.tablednd.js](https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD). But it doesn't seem to meet my specific requirements.

1. (dynamically) Enable/disable the draggability of some/all of rows.
2. Trigger a callback event for the dragged rows.
3. Handle range that the **each** rows could move around.

Please recommend me any javascript based plugins.

Because my rows are hierarchical I need `3`, but I think it may not possible.

But `1,2` looks quite reasonable function.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is totally subjective as there are many tools meeting those requirement (at least 1 and 2). For 3 you might have to tweak around a little, but the Dojo Framework has support for that:

[Dojo EnhancedGrid DnD](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/DnD.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have made good experiences with [dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/). There is a comparison of several js-grids on their website.
It supports 1+2 out of the box. Number 3 could be done by using a tree and allowing only the root nodes to be dragged. Support for touch interfaces (mobile devices).